# How costly is deadlock detection?

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock, guava

I wonder how complicated is a `Lock` detecting cycles and what overhead it has. Actually, I believe it should be rather simple, but the lack of it in Java makes me unsure.

There's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1194647/581205) recommending to use `tryLock`, but this detection is IMHO something the language should provide out of the box (as an option).

The only similar thing I've found is Guava's [CycleDetectingLockFactory](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/CycleDetectingLockFactory.java), but it has some non-trivial overhead and [doesn't try](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1538) to catch all deadlocks.

Comment: what about banker's algorithm?

Comment: @Trying: No.... it makes two totally inadequate assumptions: 1. each thread knows in advance what it may need. 2. there are multiple instances of each resource. The Banker's algorithm might work for some problems, but without the assumptions met, it can't do nothing.

Comment: The question is not how much it cost but how much other programmers are willing to sacrifice to allow you to use locking carelessly. Some would give you not even a single CPU clock cycle. So the best advice is: clean up your code instead of asking for automatic solutions. Especially as the detection still doesn't solve the problem. It will only tell you about it. By the way: the JVM *has* deadlock detection, but it's not automatic; it's triggered by thread stack dumps.

Comment: If possible use ordered locks (not sure what the technical term is), so deadlocks are impossible.

Comment: @Holger: Other programmers don't have to pay anything at all as the detection can be optional. By having a `DeadlockDetectingLockFactory` in addition to a `StandardLockFactory` it's completely free. But I might agree that the JVM detection is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

It is potentially O(N**3) I believe, as you could hold X locks on objects which are each being waited on by Y other threads which could hold Z locks each. And then you have to topologically sort them to detect a cycle.