# How can I get the amount of times that a thread tries to access a synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads running, and 5 methods on a single object, and both threads can access the 5 methods. 3 of the methods are synchronized.

So if method 1 to method 3 is synchronized, and let's say thread 1 is using method 1. Then by my understanding thread 2 won't be able to access neither method 1, 2 nor 3 on the same object... Until thread 1 finishes executing method 1 (Let me know if that interpretation is correct).

My question is how can I get the amount of times that thread 2 tried to get access to a lock on the same object, Or the amount of times that thread 2 tried to access a synchronized method while it was being used by another thread in java?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. Why are you asking this question? What concerete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1194606/6870430

Comment: I just want to keep track of the attempts so I can analyze the data in the future. So I can make the threads execute in a more efficient way @JBNizet

Comment: guess you better measure the total time a thread is waiting to lock a monitor rather than the number of attempts (and that number is a constant as Rahul Vedpathak explained).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some thread has got monitor access and is executing , then other thread will try only once. And will be blocked till it can enter the synchronized method/block.
So each thread will try only once to enter synchronized method/block and if doesn't get the monitor, it will wait indefinitely.

Maybe if you don't want to wait indefinitely, you can use ReEntrant locks and implement retry mechanism with timeout.

Comment: Do you know how I can implement this retry mechanism?

Comment: There is a method - "java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.tryLock(long, TimeUnit)" which you can use. If it didn't acquire the lock within specified time, you can use retry.

Comment: Also even if I don't implement the retry mechanism is there a way to know which thread acquired the lock first? Because if thread 1 got the lock first, I would still  like to record that "thread 1 attempted to access 0 times and thread 2 attempted to access 1 time"

Comment: You can log the name of the thread which got the Lock("Thread.getCurrentThread().getName()") and is executing the block of code.